# How do I nest dynamic tables in wicket?

Tags: java, listview, html-table, wicket

I'm using wicket to display a list of tables.  The number of tables, and the number of rows in each table, are both dynamic.

I'm trying to keep it simple and use a RepeatingView for each, and nest them, but wicket says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A child with id 'table' already exists

Here is my Java:

```
   RepeatingView view = new RepeatingView("listoftables");

    for (CCSubscription sub: getCustomer().getSubscriptions())  {

        //resource balance table
        ResourceBalance[] resBals = sub.getResourceBalances();
        if(resBals!=null && resBals.length>0)   {
        ListView<ResourceBalance> resBalTable = new ListView<ResourceBalance>("table", Arrays.asList(resBals)) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem<ResourceBalance> item) {
                ResourceBalance bal = item.getModelObject();
                item.add(new Label("resource", bal.getResource().getName()));
                item.add(new Label("balance", bal.getBalance()));
            }
        };
        view.add(resBalTable);
        }   //end if sub has non-null resource balance

    }   //end loop through subscriptions

    add(view);
```

And my html is :

```
<ul>
<li wicket:id="listoftables">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Resource Balances</b>
</legend>
    <table class="dataview" style="width:50%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headers">
                <th>Resource</th>
                <th>Balance</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr wicket:id="table">
            <td>
                <span wicket:id="resource"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span wicket:id="balance"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<br/>
```

I concede that I'm probably going about this the wrong way, but I can't see what the right way should be.

Hope someone can help!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I got it working:

```
final ListView<CCSubscription> tables = new ListView<CCSubscription>(
            "tables", getCustomer().getSubscriptions()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<CCSubscription> item) {
            ListView<ResourceBalance> resBalTable = new ListView<ResourceBalance>("listview", Arrays.asList(item.getModel().getObject().getResourceBalances())) {

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem<ResourceBalance> item) {
                    ResourceBalance bal = item.getModelObject();
                    item.add(new Label("resource", bal.getResource().getName()));
                    item.add(new Label("balance", bal.getBalance()+""));
                }
            };
            item.add(resBalTable);
        }
    };

    add(tables);
```

And the html looks as follows:

```
<span wicket:id="tables">
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Resource Balances</b>
</legend>
    <table class="dataview" style="width:50%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="headers">
                <th>Resource</th>
                <th>Balance</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr wicket:id="listview">
            <td>
                <span wicket:id="resource"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span wicket:id="balance"></span>
            </td>


        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
<br/>
```

Comment: <span wicket:id="tables"> can also put on <tbody wicket:id="tables">

Answer (score 2):

You can't add two components with the same ID (`ListView("table")`) to a single container (`RepeatingView`).

The `RepeatingView` object has a method that generates IDs for its child components. From the [javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/RepeatingView.html):

```
RepeatingView view = new RepeatingView("repeater");
view.add(new Label(view.newChildId(), "hello"));
view.add(new Label(view.newChildId(), "goodbye"));
view.add(new Label(view.newChildId(), "good morning"));
add(view);
```

You can also create your own logic to generate IDs:

```
RepeatingView view = new RepeatingView("repeater");
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    view.add(new MyListView("list" + i));
add(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the same object multiple times in your loop, which isn't what you're trying to achieve. A named component can only be added once to a given page.

You need to define your class as an extension of ListView and pass the list of objects to be rendered to it. Take a look here https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/listview-and-other-repeaters.html